# Cannot export tamil from phpmyadmin correctly

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, joomla2.5, tamil

in phpmyadmin i set charset to utf-8, tamil text looks great

```
தொடக்கத்தில் கடவுள் விண்ணுலகையும், மண்ணுலகையும் படைத்தபொழுது,
```

but after export to sql file, looks:

```
ŕ®¤ŕŻŠŕ®źŕ®•ŕŻŤŕ®•ŕ®¤ŕŻŤŕ®¤ŕ®żŕ®˛ŕŻŤ ŕ®•ŕ®źŕ®µŕŻŕ®łŕŻŤ ŕ®µŕ®żŕ®ŁŕŻŤŕ®ŁŕŻŕ®˛ŕ®•ŕŻŕ®ŻŕŻŕ®®ŕŻŤ, ŕ®®ŕ®ŁŕŻŤŕ®ŁŕŻŕ®˛ŕ®•ŕŻŕ®ŻŕŻŕ®®ŕŻŤ ŕ®Şŕ®źŕŻŕ®¤ŕŻŤŕ®¤ŕ®ŞŕŻŠŕ®´ŕŻŕ®¤ŕŻ,
```

where is problem?

Comment: can you show how you are exporting to file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly certain the SQL file's encoding is in something other than UTF8.

Try this:

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3 
FROM table1 
INTO OUTFILE 'godly_passage.txt' 
CHARACTER SET utf8
```